# Add second barplot to existing one manually (using add=T)

Tags: r, bar-chart

Is there a way in base R to manually add a second barplot to an existing one. I know how to do it if the two series are from the same data object (using `barplot( ... beside=T)`) or I guess one could draw rectangles (`rect(...)`) which `barplot` wraps. If your data is from different objects how can you then do it with the `barplot` function ? How to control bar positions?

I tried this using the space parameter (obviously not working):

```
h1 <- c(10,5,1)
h2 <- c(8, 3, 1)
barplot(h1, width = 0.5, space = 2, col='red')
barplot(h2, width = 0.5, space = 2.5, col='blue', add=T)
```

It is impossible to get the bars besides each other as when using the `beside=T` argument.

[image]

Desired output is something along this:

```
barplot(matrix(c(h1, h2), nrow=2, byrow=T), beside=T, col=c('red', 'blue'))
```

[image]

**UPDATE: how it works**

In order for me to finally - I hope - understand the width and space arguments, we can plot an axis and play with the parameters for the blue data.

```
barplot(h1, width = 0.5, space = 2, col='red')
axis(1, seq(0, 10, 0.5)) #way out of the plot region
barplot(h2, width = 0.25, space = c(4,2,4), col='blue', add=T)
```

[image]

From this it seem as (correct me if I am wrong):

**1.** `width` is the width of each bar - recycled as necessary

**2.** `space` controls the space to the previous bar (to the left) or to 0 for the first bar, and is calculated as width*space for the current bar - recycled as necessary. So the first blue bar starts at (space to 0) 0.25*4 = 1 and its right side is at 1+0.25 = 1.25; the second bar starts at 1.25+0.25*2 = 1.75, and its right side is at 1.75+0.25 = 2. And so forth...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
h1 <- c(10,5,1)
h2 <- c(8, 3, 1)
barplot(h1, width = 0.5, space = 2, col='red')
barplot(h2, width = 0.5, space = c(3,2,2), col='blue', add=T)
```

And this will be the output:

[image]

Comment: I must have misunderstood the space argument (from manual: the amount of space (as a fraction of the average bar width) left before each bar. May be given as a single number or one number per bar. So when you give c(3,2,2) everything is moved 1 (compared to 2 (aka c(2,2,2) ) - is that is?

Comment: Exactly. Each element specifies the space for each bar. That's the same thing that you do when using `beside = T`. Default for there is `space = c(0,1)` which means the bars for different groups are beside each other and there's 1 unit space between each pair.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as they were almost identical, at the exception that I had included `xlim=c(1,5)` in the first `barplot`, as I would otherwise get the last blue bar partly outside the plot.

Comment: @Lamia You did not specify the width. If I remember right.

Comment: @Masoud indeed I hadn't included `width`, but even if I reproduce your code, it somehow only works if I also specify `xlim`.

Comment: @Lamia You have my approval if you want to go ahead and include some edits to make the graph visually appealing.